# Is there a way to request twitter information without a twitter account?

Tags: twitter, httprequest

I just want to get information like the latest tweets from public accounts. If not, is there a simple oauth option that will allow me to have access to tweets of public accounts if I create a twitter account?

Comment: You need an account in order to create your own Twitter apps - https://apps.twitter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests to the Twitter API must be authenticated, which means that there needs to be an account associated with the request.

There is no "simple" OAuth option.  There are a number of OAuth libraries available for you to use in almost any language you want, so you don't have to write your own implementation.